# Exchangeability with random effects?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a $N\times N$ random matrix 
$$
\epsilon:=
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_{11} & \epsilon_{12}  & \dots &\epsilon_{1N} \\
\epsilon_{21} & \epsilon_{22}  & \dots    & \epsilon_{2N} \\
\vdots         & \vdots      & \ddots   & \vdots         \\
\epsilon_{N1}  & \dots          & \dots & \epsilon_{NN}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$\epsilon$ is exchangeable if 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_{11} & \epsilon_{12}  & \dots &\epsilon_{1N} \\
\epsilon_{21} & \epsilon_{22}  & \dots    & \epsilon_{2N} \\
\vdots         & \vdots      & \ddots   & \vdots         \\
\epsilon_{N1}  & \dots          & \dots & \epsilon_{NN}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is distributed as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_{\varphi{(1)}\varphi{(1)}} & \epsilon_{\varphi{(1)}\varphi{(2)}}  & \dots &\epsilon_{\varphi{(1)}\varphi{(N)}} \\
\epsilon_{\varphi{(2)}\varphi{(1)}} & \epsilon_{\varphi{(2)}\varphi{(2)}}  & \dots    & \epsilon_{\varphi{(2)}\varphi{(N)}} \\
\vdots         & \vdots      & \ddots   & \vdots         \\
\epsilon_{\varphi{(N)}\varphi{(1)}}  & \dots          & \dots & \epsilon_{\varphi{(N)}\varphi{(N)}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for any permutation $\varphi$.

I know that if $\epsilon_{ij}$ are i.i.d. across $i,j$, then $\epsilon$ is exchangeable.

My question is: suppose $\epsilon_{ij}:=u_{ij}+\alpha$ where $u_{ij}$ are i.i.d. across $i,j$, $\alpha_i$ are i.i.d across $i$ and $\alpha_i$ is independent of $u_i$, i.e.
$$
\epsilon:=
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{11}+ \alpha_1 & u_{12}+ \alpha_1  & \dots  &u_{1N}+ \alpha_1 \\
u_{21}+ \alpha_2 & u_{22}+ \alpha_2  & \dots    &u_{2N}+ \alpha_2\\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots   & \vdots         \\
u_{N1}+ \alpha_N  & \dots  & \dots      & u_{NN}+ \alpha_N\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is $\epsilon$ defined in this way exchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

In fact, for any two exchangeable random matrices $A$ and $B$ independent of each other, $A+B$ will also be exchangeable.

The matrix $U=[u_{ij}]$ is exchangeable since it is assumed to be i.i.d., and $A=[a_{ij}]$ where $a_{ij}=\alpha_i$ is exchangeable since the permutation on $A$ simply acts as a permutation on the $\alpha_i$ (also exchangeable since it is i.i.d.).

In fact, it would be sufficient to assume that $U$ and $[\alpha_i]$ are exchangeable and independent.

The proof of the exchangeability of $A+B$ is a mere technicality, I suppose. If $\psi$ is a permutation, and we  for any matrix $M=[m_{ij}]$ denote the permutation as $\psi(M)=[m_{\psi(i)\psi(j)}]$, then $A$ and $\psi(A)$ have the same distribution, and $B$ and $\psi(B)$ have the same distribution. Since they are independent, that makes $A+B$ and $\psi(A+B)=\psi(A)+\psi(B)$ also have identical distributions.